# Show delegate derived from in debug mode

Tags: c#, delegates

I have delegate:

```
    public delegate void PhotoFilterHandler(Photo photo);
```

Creating variable:

```
PhotoProcessor.PhotoFilterHandler filterhandler = ApplyBrightnes;
```

Why I can't see what it derived from in debug mode:

[image]

I'm expecting to get something like one from training video:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. The debug window you show clearly shows the `ApplyBrightness()` method as the target for the delegate. What is it you expected to see? What are you asking?

Comment: I expect to seed `base [System.MulticastDelegate]` in my debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit unclear but if you are trying to know the base type then you can use the `BaseType` property like below and as usual it's a `MultiCastDelegate`

```
typeof(PhotoFilterHandler).BaseType.Name
```